# Can I create an object in ios (ARC) that has a function call with a block, and not set null in the end? Will it have a memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks

Can I create an object in ios (ARC) that has a function call with a block, and not set null in the end? Will it have a memory leak?

Here is an example code:

```
WebService *webService = [[WebService alloc] init]; 
[webService request:getPriceSheet callbackBlock:^(BaseResponseMsg *responseMsg){ 
   ...
}];
```

When is the WebService object dealocated? Is there here a memory leak? Is it dealocated after that the block was called.

Do I need to put the object in a property so that it will dealocate when the viewcontroller is left?

Comment: No compiler handle it automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's written, with no extra knowledge of what `request:callbackBlock:` does, `webService` may be released when the current scope ends and the callback will never execute.

Likely, and usually, a method like `request:callbackBlock:` will put the webService object indirectly into a queue, or as a temporarily strongly retained delegate to another process. When webService is no longer referenced by the `request`-related infrastructure, it will be released.

Take this with a grain of salt. Without knowing the characteristics of `request:callbackBlock:`, it is impossible to know who may retain a reference to `webService`.

Comment: What does it mean "Likely, and usually"? Isn't the compiler working consistently. Or that it adds it to the queue or that it doesn't put it in the queue?

Comment: I mean the answer to your question depends on the implementation of  `request:callbackBlock:`. It is standard practice to briefly retain the service, then release it on completion. But that is not guaranteed. Its documentation should indicate its behavior.

There is probably not a leak in the code you provided. If anything, the service is not retained  and it may not exist to process the request upon completion.

It is also possible `WebService` doesn't follow standard patterns and requires additional management. This is all about the implementation of the service, not the compiler.